# firefox toolbar event

Tags: firefox, events, firefox-addon, toolbar

Does anyone know who to find an event occurrence on a toolbar in firefox.
I want to do event logging on toolbar in firefox.

Thanks

Comment: I presume you mean from in custom Firefox add-on?  Or do you think this can be done in Javascript?

Answer (score 9):

Please follow the link, this gives you ideas and code snippets how you can be notified of any event using your toolbar. There's an example as well, you can further extend it or use it in your own ways.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners#Example.3a_Notification_when_the_value_in_Address_Bar_changes

Hope this helps:)